# What would be the next approximate stable value of Higgs VeV after 246 GeV, assuming that it's metastable?

Tags: higgs

Based on the top mass, the Higgs boson mass and assuming that there is nothing beyond the standard model, what is the approximate next stable vev of the Higgs field if the field is in a metastable state at 246 GeV.